# How to check case sensitivity of username when login to a site in MVC 5 using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I Need Help to check Case Sensitivity of LoginId & Password Like Admin and Password : SsA.123 but currently it takes admin as LoginId and ssa.123 as Passwod.

```
public static class LoginValidation
{
     //VALIDATE LOGIN AND GET USER NAME AND USER ID FOR FUTURE USE
     public static bool Validate_Login(string first_input, string password, DBEntities db, out string Name, out int id)
     {

         Name = db.MAST_User.Where(x => x.LoginId == first_input).Select(x =>  x.UserName).FirstOrDefault();//GET USER NAME TO DISPLAY AFTER LOGIN

         id = db.MAST_User.Where(x => x.LoginId == first_input).Select(x => x.MastId).FirstOrDefault();             //GET USER ID TO CHECK RIGHTS

         return db.MAST_User.First(x => x.LoginId == first_input).Password == password ? true : false;             //RETURNS BOOLEAN VALUE TRUE OR FALSE
     }

}
```

Comment: In general, users expect usernames to be case insensitive.  Almost all systems do not differentiate the case of username.  Passwords are case sensitive, but you should NEVER store clear text passwords in your database.  You should store hash values and compare the hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison query is executing within the database server and it may have set to be case insensitive (for example SQL server is case insensitive by default).

Easiest way would be to bring your query results to memory by converting it to an `Array()/List()/Variable` and then compare within `C#` code. Ex;

```
//Load into memory
var users = db.MAST_User.Where(x => x.LoginId == first_input).ToArray(); 

//Compare in C#
if(users.Any(u=> u.LoginId == first_input && u.Password == password))
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

On a separate note, please check your `FirstOrDefault()` object for `null` before assigning its properties to other variables.